# Reorder RecyclerView items position with custom adapter and without

Tags: java, android, collections, android-recyclerview, comparator

Today I have this problem:
I am trying to change an item position depending on an important factor.
What I mean is: if my object has a string that equals to a specific value (I get before this method) XX, it should be added at the first position of my RecyclerView.
Else at its normal position.
So I am just doing it in my RecyclerView Activity by

```
if (myString.equals("XX")) {
            studi.add(0, s); //here if it respect the if statement goes to at the top position
        }
        //else its normal pos.
        else {
            studi.add(s); 
        }
```

After is set the RecyclerView adapter with the "studi" customArray...

The problem is that I am using comparator on myAdapter that sorts all my RecyclerView items and even though I add the item at the index 0, my comparator set at the position it says.
So how can I do what I want?
I hope I explained my problem well.
If not sorry.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> implements Filterable {

Context c;
ArrayList<Studi> studi;
ArrayList<Studi> filterList;
CustomFilter filter;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Studi> studi) {
    this.c = c;
    this.studi = studi;
    this.filterList = studi;
    //ordina per vicinanza

    Collections.sort(studi, new Comparator<Studi>() {
        public int compare(Studi s1, Studi s2) {
            //solo se non sono annunci
            if (s1.getDistanza() != null && s2.getDistanza() != null) {
                return Integer.parseInt(s1.getDistanza()) - Integer.parseInt(s2.getDistanza());
            } else return 1;
        }
    });

    //se gli studi non hanno la distanza vanno infondo
    Collections.sort(studi, new Comparator<Studi>() {
        public int compare(Studi s1, Studi s2) {
            boolean item1Match = s1.getDistanza() == null;
            boolean item2Match = s2.getDistanza() == null;
            if (item1Match == item2Match) {
                return 0;
            }
            return item1Match ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model, parent, false);
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (studi == null) ? 0 : studi.size();
}

//FILTER THING......................
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new CustomFilter(filterList, this);
    }
    return filter;
}
}
```

Comment: You can try adding the condition to your comparator, i.e., always return a high value (e.g. Integer.MAX_VALUE) when the object being compared has your string

Comment: You mean at the same comparator?

Comment: Yes have you tried that?